# How to get to Strings dynamically

Tags: android, string, textview

I have some strings and I want to get each string according to a number. For example. I have the Strings:

```
<string name="ln1">Line1</string>
<string name="ln2">Line2</string>
<string name="ln3">Line3</string>
```

And here is my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 2;
    box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    box.setText(R.string.ln1);
    box.setOnClickListener(this);}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    box.setText(R.string.ln+ counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Right now, the text gets displayed as "R.string.ln2" when I click the TextView. How do I set up the `TextView` to display the next string (i.e: ln2) when I click the `TextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be better off using string arrays in your resource file if you want to have a collection of strings to loop through:

```
<string-array name="somename">
    <item>Line1</item>
    <item>Line2</item>
    <item>Line3</item>
</string-array>
```

And then access it in the code:

```
String[] lines;
int counter = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lines = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.somename);
    box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    box.setText(lines[0]);
    box.setOnClickListener(this);}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    box.setText(lines[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. As simple as that. Guess I was going about it the long way around. Indeed, using an array is much simple and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the `<string>` tags using: `R.string.string_name`

Example:

```
String lineOne = getResources().getString(R.string.ln1);
```

OR you can directly set the string to a TextView or any other widget:

```
setText(R.string.ln2);
```

Comment: setText(R.string.ln2); here R.string.ln2 will return int so you can not user thay expression..

Comment: @SanketKachhela Go ahead and try it. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the string array

```
 <string name="ln1">Line1</string>
 <string name="ln2">Line2</string>
 <string name="ln3">Line3</string>
```

Java file

```
String[] value;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 value[0] = R.string.ln1;
 value[1] = R.string.ln2;
 value[2] = R.string.ln3;
 counter = 0;
 box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 box.setText(R.string.ln1);
 box.setOnClickListener(this);}

 @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
  box.setText(value[counter]);
  counter = counter + 1;
  }
```